# error while running command truffle init

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am new to smart contract programming, recently installed truffle using npm on Node(9.11.1)  When I run the command truffle init first time, I received this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'original-require'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\saura\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\external "original-require":1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\saura\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 1e465420bd4a8d34abd9:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\saura\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-config\index.js:8:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\saura\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:2394:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\saura\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 1e465420bd4a8d34abd9:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\saura\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-core\cli.js:3:1)
```

Any suggestions to resolve this error.

Comment: Its sending you on a quest to find the mystical `original-require` module. Bring that to it, and you might get a new quest.

Comment: @Derek not finding "original-require" library in the path

Comment: This might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/original-require

Answer (score 1):

I think you need run this command:

`npm install original-require`